# Is my proof for $X\times Y = Y\times X\Leftrightarrow X=Y$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I used an indirect proof for $"\Rightarrow"$: Let $X\neq Y$. That means that there exists $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ with $(x,y)\neq(y,x)$. Because of
$$
(x,y)=(x',y')\Leftrightarrow (x=x')\wedge (y=y')
$$
we have $X\times Y\neq Y\times X$.

For the other direction $"\Leftarrow"$ I used a direct proof. Let $X=Y$. That means
$$
X=Y\Leftrightarrow(X\subset Y)\wedge (Y\subset X) \Leftrightarrow (\forall x\in X\Rightarrow x\in Y) \wedge(\forall y\in Y\Rightarrow y\in X).  
$$
Therefore we have
$$
X\times Y \subset X\times X\subset Y\times Y\subset Y\times X
$$
and
$$
Y\times X\subset Y\times Y \subset X\times X \subset X \times Y
$$
which means
$$
(X\times Y\subset Y\times X)\wedge (Y\times X \subset X\times Y) \Leftrightarrow X=Y.
$$
The thing is I am not sure whether this is proof is complete or if I did something wrong (or skipped a step somewhere). Could someone help me out?

Comment: $X\times\varnothing=\varnothing=\varnothing\times X$ for every set $X$.

Comment: Oh of course. I assumed that bot sets would be non empty. Thank you! Do you see any other mistakes?

Comment: Your proof is at least unclear. I would recommend to prove in general that for non-empty sets $A,B,C,D$ we have: $A\times B=C\times D\iff A=C\wedge B=D$. On base of that it follows directly that for non-empty $X,Y$ we have $X\times Y=Y\times X\iff X=Y$. Here $\impliedby$ is direct.

Comment: Of X and Y are the same thing, then XxX and XxY are the same thing: one does not need to prove this, it is part of what "being the same thing" means!

Comment: I think you confused the directions. Your indirect proof (better said by contrapositive) seems for $\Leftarrow$ and your direct proof for $\Rightarrow.$ Moreover, your "indirect proof" is flawed. The existence of those $x,y$ does not prove that $X\times Y\ne Y\times X.$ (also, mind the typo, you wrote $Y\ne X$ instead of $Y\times X$)